# vgg = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19 not sure model is properly loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to move a Colab example  *Neural Style Transfer with Eager Execution* to run on my Windows 10 machine.  I have made appropriate changes to get the Style and Content images.

It appears that:

```
 vgg = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

the `vgg99` model is not being executed properly (or maybe not found) or at all. below is the output of the model where it hangs.

***Iteration: 0***

```
Total loss: 5.7769e+08, style loss: 5.7769e+08,
content loss: 0.0000e+00, time: 0.0040*s
```

Iterations are set for `1000` in the code.  This code works fine when run in `Colab`.

Is the `vgg19` model not being found?

Comment: Your are not describing the problem properly, I don't understand at all what you mean by "vgg19 model not being found?"

Comment: I was concerned that vgg19 was not properly installed. Turns out it is on my system. I "solved" the problem. See my response post

Answer (score 0):

OOPS!!

The program is running afterall!!  I left the program running after the first iteration dispaly and had lunch. Came back and it was up to 800 iterations. I am running on a 4.2 ghz I& with no GPU. I'm still surprised how long it takes.